# Firestore Security Rules: Insufficient permissions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I need some help making my security rules for firestore work.

These are my firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      function isAdmin(uid) {
        return (uid in get(/admin/administrators).data.uid)
      }
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && isAdmin(request.auth.uid);
    }
  }
}
```

In document `/admin/administrators` there is a field named `uid` containing an array of UIDs of administrators which are allowed to write in the database.

After I logged in as one such administrator and tried to add a document to another collection. (Specifically, the call in my Angular application using Angularfire 2 is `this.afStore.collection(collection).add({});`) I received the error `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

Any help appreciated (including "there's obviously a better way to do this")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter the absolute path of the collection you're trying to reference. Change the `(uid in get(/admin/administrators).data.uid)` to `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/admin/$(request.auth.uid)).data.uid`